# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants:

Tags: corda

I have a Use case where I have to send complaint details (Complaint is a ledger ie IOUState.class)to two operators ( say JIO and Airtel) from Sender operator (TTL)

State class constructor has complaint details and three Operators (Party objects), One sender and two receivers.

The first part of the user case is executing fine and transaction/complaints details are getting logged in Vault state/Linear state.

The second part of the transaction involves one of the receiver operator sending complaint resolution response to the sender operator and should not be sending compliant response to third operator. ie Say complaint is related to Airtel then Airtel will respond to TTL and JIO needs to be out of loop.

I have written one state class and two flow classes.

But when I execute the second flow (Airtel to TTL) it is throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants: [O=PartyJIO, L=MUMBAI, C=IN]

I have created the transaction with Command requiring only two Signers , TTL and Airtel but dont know why still getting the error

//Flow class in Airtel Node, TAP is TTL Node

List requiredSigners = Arrays.asList(getOurIdentity().getOwningKey(), TAP.getOwningKey());

Command command = new Command<>(new IOUContract.Create(), requiredSigners);

```
  txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
            .addInputState(IOUState1.get(0))
            .addOutputState(outputState, IOUContract.ID)
            .addCommand(command);
```

FlowSession otherPartySession1 = initiateFlow(TAP); //TAP is TTL Party Object
//Otherpartysession1 is getting executed at Airtel node

```
    SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
            signedTx, Arrays.asList(otherPartySession1), CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()));
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants:

```
SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
            signedTx, Arrays.asList(otherPartySession1), CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()));
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants:

Comment: remove jio from the list of participants.

Comment: I have one state class. In overridden getparticipants function, i m checking whether variable to store jio is not null, then i m including three participants ttl, airtel, jio this is required for first transaction. If variable to store jio party is null, then i m including ttl, airtel as return participants. Hence for second transaction, it should return two participants only

Comment: have you added  subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx, listOfSession))

Comment: Yes. I have added it. List of session is only one. Ie airtel to ttl

Comment: Then double check the participants list print there names on the console.

Comment: Dear Arun,Please find the part of Flow code FlowSession otherPartySession1 = initiateFlow(TAP);
        SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
                signedTx, Arrays.asList(otherPartySession1), CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()));
       subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx,otherPartySession1));

Comment: getParticipants in state class:@Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        if(OtherOperators2 != null) {
            System.out.println("Three Particiants" + TAP.toString() + " " + OtherOperators1.toString() + " " + OtherOperators2.toString());
            return Arrays.asList(TAP, OtherOperators1, OtherOperators2);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Two Particiants" + TAP.toString() + " " + OtherOperators1.toString());
            return Arrays.asList(TAP, OtherOperators1);
        }
    }

Comment: I think When the subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, otherSession1); is getting called the getParticipants is called twice. Below is console output Two ParticiantsO=PartyAirtel, L=Delhi, C=IN O=PartyAirtel, L=Delhi, C=IN
Three ParticiantsO=PartyTTL, L=Delhi, C=IN O=PartyAirtel, L=Delhi, C=IN O=PartyJIO, L=MUMBAI, C=IN------ In first SOP output correct parties are reflecting but not sure why second line is getting printed that too with all parties including JIO

Answer (score 2):

(Developer Relations @ R3 here)

In Corda 4, you are required to pass FinalityFlow a list of sessions that includes all of the transaction's participants, so that the transaction can be distributed accordingly.

Just because someone is in this list of participants, it does not make them a required signer. The required signers are determined by the public keys listed on the transaction's commands.

Comment: Dear Chris, Agreed to ur point. Therefore in my code, where from one node i have to send response details to another node, i have two signers or public keys required. One for sender n another for receiver. Initiate flow hence has only one session. But the error being returned is referring to include the flow session to node which i dont want to communicate with.  Just to repeat the usecase, in first transaction node ttl is communicating with node airtel n node jio. Fo

Comment: Which is working fine. In second transaction, node airtel needs to communicate with node ttl n not to node jio. But i m getting exception to include flow session to node jio from node airtel for second transaction which i dont want

Comment: Right, ok -- I think I get it .. maybe :)

If what you're trying to do is to send information to the third node, without it being a required signatory, you could initiate a flow session, and then use otherPartySession1.send() to send information over to it.

If however you want it to be a signatory after the first two parties have signed, that wouldn't be possible with corda, as it requires all signatories to be included in the collect signatures stage. By calling collect signatures twice and including otherPartySession1 in the second call, it thinks it should've been included in the fist

Comment: Thanks Chris for answering. But the requirement is not to send details to third node when the second transaction is being processed.

Comment: Usecase is node ttl is sending details to node jio and node airtel in first transaction. This is working fine. As a response to details received, node airtel wants to respond to node ttl only. Transaction is not supposed to be known to node JIO but needs to be logged in node ttl and node airtel ledger

Comment: Flows are based on the assumption that all the signers of a transaction are participants -- I think in this case you might want to trigger an entirely new flow that has it's own transaction & signers between ttl and airtel

Comment: Dear Chris, I have written different flow classes for the first and second transaction. But State class is same with one constructor.

Comment: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html has some example code on how to implement notifying a 3rd node using separate flows

Answer (score 0):

Anthony Keenan also looked at this and, on [this page](https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2705) found out

`The PartyB that is resolved from the transaction has an owning key that is different to the owning key in serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities so it thinks it's an 'external participant' and expects a flow session passing in.`

So.. it may be the case you have recreated your keys somehow.